# How to read a specific line of a file to a variable in python using enumerate?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, enumerate

In python I have a small piece of code that takes an integer input and reads through a file, going to the line inputted and reading that line to a variable. However, when checking to make sure the correct thing was assigned to the variable, the number that was inputted by the user was assigned to the variable, not what was on the line.

I have looked through posts that are quite similar to this and have used those pieces of code to create this.

What I have so far is the following:

```
    with open("accounts.txt") as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            if i == Access:
                account = i
                break

# 'Access' is an integer, such as 1
# print(account) returns that integer rather than the string on that line in the file
```

The answer is probably very obvious and I'm not seeing it, but all solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: `account = line` ??

Comment: since `account = i`  `print(account)` will give you `1`

Comment: "The answer is probably very obvious and I'm not seeing it" --- yes. I think that this should be closed as a simple typo.

Comment: Hello! You should not "close" your question editing the title. Instead, accept the answer which you judge the most useful. Please, take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for a quick overview of how stackoverflow works and read [what to do when someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print(account) returns that integer rather than the string on that line in the file` because you are printing the iteration of the loop rather than the line itself.

You just need to replace `account = i` with `account = line` and you are read to go.

Answer (score 0):

`account = i` should be `account = line`